# How to update filename recursively

Tags: bash, sh

I have properties files like
    Abc_name_0.1.properties
    xyz_name1_0.2.properties 
    Dfg_zxc_1.0.properties 
Output :
 Abc_name_1.3.5.properties
xyz_name1_1.3.5.properties
Dfg_zxc_1.3.5.properties

I want to modify numbers (0.1/0.2/1.0 ) with a new string recursively in the shell script.

I am using the `find` command to find `.properties` files and want to rename just numbers from it. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: Please include a small set of sample data (or filenames) to be modified, the required output from that data (filenames), your current code, output and exact text of any error messages generated. Any code at all makes us think you are trying to solve your problem and not just asking people to do your job for you.  As is this is too board and will likely be voted to close. Good luck.

Comment: Do you know how to do it *without* anything being recursive? (If so, that gives us a more narrow and specific question -- how to modify your existing code to run a little differently). If you don't, consider breaking this down into two smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is relatively complicated for this. It's easier to use globstar (to enable recursive globs) and `rename` (the Perl version).

You haven't mentioned specifics, but hopefully this gets you started:

```
shopt -s globstar
# Remove the "-n" option if the output looks good
rename -v -n 's/[0-9]\.[0-9](?=\.properties$)/newstr/' **/*.properties
```

Breakdown:

- `rename -v -n` - Perl `rename` with verbose and no-act options

  - `'s/pattern/repl/'` - Perl "substitute": replace regex *pattern* with *repl*

    - `[0-9]\.[0-9]` - A digit, a literal dot, then another digit
    - `(?=\.properties$)` - Regex lookahead to ensure that it only matches numbers immediately before the file extension `.properties`
    - `newstr` - Replace this with your desired string
- `**/*.properties` - Recursive glob: `**` matches zero or more subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

You could just use pax:

```
mkdir ../foo
pax -rw -s /0.1/repl1/g -s /0.2/repl2/g . ../foo
```

Will recursively copy everything in the current working directory into ../foo, with the renames as specified by the -s options.  Or

`pax -rw -s /^dir/foo/ -s /0.1/repl1/g -s /0.2/repl2/g dir .`

To copy everything in `dir/` to the sibling directory `foo/`